# Google cloud storage insert object returns Invalid Credentials 401

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I am working on google cloud storage, i hv created bucket using java code, but when i insert object inside bucket i face the below problem.

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.storage.appengine.StorageSampleServlet.doGet(StorageSampleServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.servlet.auth.oauth2.AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.service(AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(ResourceFileServlet.java:342)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(ResourceFileServlet.java:281)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.doGet(ResourceFileServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please find below code

```
@Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the stored credentials using the Authorization Flow
    AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = initializeFlow();
    Credential credential = authFlow.loadCredential(getUserId(req));
    // Build the Storage object using the credentials
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(
        Utils.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Utils.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream("Book1.csv");
    long byteCount = 500000;

    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", inputStream);
 mediaContent.setLength(byteCount);

    StorageObject objectMetadata = null;
Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert("mnbvcxz_2", objectMetadata,
        mediaContent);

    insertObject.setName("myobjeas1");
 if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= 2 * 1000 * 1000 /* 2MB */) {
      insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    }

    insertObject.execute();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go to: https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~yourappname/storage , then check the checkbox next to the bucket, and click "Bucket Permissions" above.  What do you see?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. It has owner permission.